# How does passive replication work between two Windows file servers? A passive backup solution, as opposed to active

Tags: windows

I understand how active replication would work through the use of DFSR in the context of file servers, but what would passive replication look like? I am designing a failover solution to transition to a backup file server and I'm trying to implement a passive solution, but I don't precisely know what that look like process-wise. If someone could provide an explanation (like a step-by-step example), I'd deeply appreciate it. This is honestly for my own understanding.

Answer (score 0):

For native methods of failover for Windows fileservers, you have two options. One is DFS, as you've already pointed out. The other is Windows Server Clustering.

If this is the sort of thing you mean by "passive replication", https://jaksa.wordpress.com/2009/05/01/active-and-passive-replication-in-distributed-systems/ - then Windows DFS is already passive. The client doesn't write to all servers - the client connects to one server, and then the other members of the replica will sync from each other. (Badly, IME, but hey, it tries.)

Classically, Windows Server Clustering doesn't do either - it relied on shared storage for clustering, and simply connects you to one Windows server to give you access to the storage. It protects against hardware failure of a server, but depends on the shared storage staying available.

With Server 2016 and SMB3, there's now "Storage Replica", which also acts like DFS replication, although I'm sure it's much better tech on the inside. It's still probably what you think of as "passive replication."

If you mean something else by "passive replication", please cite your sources.